# passing 2 values from dropdown in php using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, dropdown

I have been creating a system as a project on school. I have encountered a problem in getting values using ajax. I wanted to get values from the qselCampus dropdown and the qselCollege dropdown, then pass its values to a php file and use it on a query that will populate the third dropdown. The problem is, I cannot get the right values on the third dropdown. I am just a beginner in PHP and AJAX.

Here is my AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#qselBranch").change(function() {
    var branchid = $(this).val();
    if(branchid != "") {
        $.ajax({
            url:"getprof.php",
            data:{txtbid:branchid},
            type:'POST',
            success:function(response) {
                var resp = $.trim(response);
                //console.log(resp);
                $("#qselProf").html(resp);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("#qselProf").html("<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>");
    }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#qselCollege").change(function() {
    var collegeid = $(this).val();
    if(collegeid != "") {
        $.ajax({
            url:"getprof.php",
            data:{txtcid:collegeid},
            type:'POST',
            success:function(response) {
                var resp = $.trim(response);
                console.log(resp);
                $("#qselProf").html(resp);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("#qselProf").html("<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>");
    }
    });
});
```

Here is my PHP Code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['txtbid'])){
    $strGetValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($objConn, $_POST['txtbid']);
    $strGetValue2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($objConn, $_POST['txtcid']);
    echo $strGetValue;
    $strStmtGetProf = "SELECT
                    strTeacherInfoID
                    , strFirstName
                    , strMiddleName
                    , strLastName
                    , strCampus
                    FROM tblteachers
                    WHERE strCampus = '$strGetValue' AND strCollege = '$strGetValue2'";
    $objResult = mysqli_query($objConn, $strStmtGetProf) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: Error: ".mysqli_error($objConn), E_USER_ERROR);
    echo "<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>";
    //echo $strGetValue2;
    while($objFetch = mysqli_fetch_array($objResult)){
        $strTID = $objFetch['strTeacherInfoID'];
        $strFirstName = $objFetch['strFirstName'];
        $strLastName = $objFetch['strLastName'];
        $strCampus = $objFetch['strCampus'];
        //echo $strGetValue;
        echo '<option value="' . $strTID . '">' .$strLastName. ", " .$strFirstName. " | Branch: " .$strCampus. '</option>';
    }
}
   ?>
```

And here is the HTML part:

```
    <div class="form-row col-md-8">
                    <label>Campus Branch
                        <select name="qselBranch" id="qselBranch" required class="form-control">
                            <option value="">------- Select --------</option>
                            <option value="Bansud">Bansud</option>
                            <option value="Bataan">Bataan</option>
                            <option value="Biñan">Biñan</option>
                            <option value="Cabiao">Cabiao</option>
                            <option value="Lopez">Lopez</option>
                            <option value="Mabini">Mabini</option>
                            <option value="Maragondon">Maragondon</option>
                            <option value="Mulanay">Mulanay</option>
                            <option value="Parañaque">Parañaque</option>
                            <option value="Pulilan">Pulilan</option>
                            <option value="Quezon">Quezon</option>
                            <option value="Ragay">Ragay</option>
                            <!--<option value="Sablayan">Sablayan</option>-->
                            <option value="San Juan">San Juan</option>
                            <option value="San Pedro">San Pedro</option>
                            <option value="Sta. Maria">Sta. Maria</option>
                            <option value="Sta. Rosa">Sta. Rosa</option>
                            <option value="Sto. Tomas">Sto. Tomas</option>
                            <option value="Taguig">Taguig</option>
                            <option value="Unisan">Unisan</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                    College/Faculty:
                        <select name="qselCollege" required class="form-control">
                            <option value="">------- Select --------</option>
                            <option value="CAF">College of Accountancy and Finance (CAF)</option>
                            <option value="CAFA">College of Architecture and Fine Arts (CAFA)</option>
                            <option value="CAL">College of Arts and Letters (CAL)</option>
                            <option value="CBA">College of Business Administration (CBA)</option>
                            <option value="COC">College of Communication (COC)</option>
                            <option value="CCIS">College of Computer and Information Sciences (CCIS)</option>
                            <option value="COED">College of Education (COED)</option>
                            <option value="CE">College of Engineering (CE)</option>
                            <option value="CHK">College of Human Kinetics (CHK)</option>
                            <option value="CL">College of Law (CL)</option>
                            <option value="CPSPA">College of Political Science and Public Administration (CPSPA)</option>
                            <option value="CSSD">College of Social Sciences and Development (CSSD)</option>
                            <option value="CS">College of Science (CS)</option>
                            <option value="CTHTM">College of Tourism, Hospitality and Transportation Management (CTHTM)</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can't find the dropdown with id `qselCollege`

Comment: its the first dropdown on the html part

Comment: I'm talking about college dropdown

Comment: ohh looks like I forgot to put an id on the second select element

Comment: Add that and check it again

Comment: An error appeared on my browser's console
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: txtbid in <b>C:\Apache24\htdocs\SoftEngProj\pages\getprof.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />

Comment: You have `data:{txtcid:collegeid},` and `if(isset($_POST['txtbid']))`, copy/paste error? You send two different data to your PHP with two different key and you make ONE $_POST test, is it normal?

Comment: Your code can't work since you make 2 different call and your php script use both of your data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you have 2 different Ajax call and you use both data in your php...even if you send them one by one. First, try to make ONE ajax call when you change a value in your form and if you have two value different than " ". It should look like this  :

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#qselBranch, #qselCollege").change(function() { // On change for each form
    var branchid = $("#selBranch").val();
    var collegeid = $("#qselCollege").val();
    if(branchid != "" && collegeid != "") { // check if both value are not empty
      $.ajax({
        url:"getprof.php",
        data:{txtbid:branchid,txtcid:collegeid}, // send both value in one time
        type:'POST',
        success:function(response) {
            var resp = $.trim(response);
            //console.log(resp);
            $("#qselProf").html(resp);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#qselProf").html("<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>");
    }
  });
});
```

PHP :

```
<?php
// I change nothing, juste add a double $_POST condition
if(isset($_POST['txtbid']) && isset($_POST['txtcid'])){
  $strGetValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($objConn, $_POST['txtbid']);
  $strGetValue2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($objConn, $_POST['txtcid']);
  echo $strGetValue;
  $strStmtGetProf = "SELECT
                strTeacherInfoID
                , strFirstName
                , strMiddleName
                , strLastName
                , strCampus
                FROM tblteachers
                WHERE strCampus = '$strGetValue' AND strCollege = 
'$strGetValue2'";
 $objResult = mysqli_query($objConn, $strStmtGetProf) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: Error: ".mysqli_error($objConn), E_USER_ERROR);
echo "<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>";
//echo $strGetValue2;
while($objFetch = mysqli_fetch_array($objResult)){
    $strTID = $objFetch['strTeacherInfoID'];
    $strFirstName = $objFetch['strFirstName'];
    $strLastName = $objFetch['strLastName'];
    $strCampus = $objFetch['strCampus'];
    //echo $strGetValue;
    echo '<option value="' . $strTID . '">' .$strLastName. ", " .$strFirstName. " | Branch: " .$strCampus. '</option>';
  }
}
?>
```

Is it what you are looking for? Tell me if it works please :)

Comment: It says error, missing } opened at line 8,column9. Sorry for the late response, cannot get into stackoverflow all of a sudden

Comment: Maybe my code have some error in it since I wrote it here, but did you understand your error at first? And for this error it's very explicit : you have an "}" opened somewhere in the code, it is in the JS or PHP?

Comment: JS i think, because it appeared on my browser's console and it pertains to a js file

Comment: Ok, try to correct all the syntax mistake and tell me if you see something wrong, but I hope you get the main point of my anwser and what was your error :)

Comment: Thank you sir, I just corrected it and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Nice, I'm happy if I could help you :)